# Trying to do some animation on image view when onPageSelected of a view pager but the animation doesn't kick in onPageSelected

Tags: android

I would like to make some animation on an image view when a specific item in the view pager is selected. But now the animation on the image view doesn't kick in when the page is selected.

```
//shake function in viewPager
 fun shakeImage()
        val rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0f, 20f, 0f, -20f, 0f)
        rotate.repeatCount = 8 // repeat the loop 20 times
        rotate.duration = 100 // animation play time 100 ms
        rotate.start()
    }
```

```java
//onPageSelected of viewPager
 @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            adapter.shakeImage();
    }
```

Comment: Why not trying to use PageTransformer? https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Comment: @Zain I'm not trying to animate the page transformation, I would like to shake the image view that is inside in the each view of the view pager.

Comment: you are calling shakeImage() on the adapter; I think it whould be in the image view within the fragment isn't it?

Comment: @Zain my view pager instantiates card views. The image view i would like to shake is inside that card view. sorry.

Comment: try instantiating the image view and call the animation function inside adapter class only.

Comment: @ViddyutKhanvilkar My application flow is like to shake the image view when it's visible to user. To do this, i chose the onPageSelected of the view pager function to activate the shake animation function that is inside the view pager adapter. Point me out if my flow is wrong. thanks for your reply.